# Masonry js won't bunch images vertically

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

The images are being aligned horizontally correctly but they are all spaced out vertically.. Take a look here http://brstudios.co.uk/testing to see what I mean properly..

My mark up is as followed (simplified):

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/master/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.break',
      columnWidth : 429
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.break {
    float: left;
    width: 429px;
    margin: 10px 20px;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="portfolio-container">

<?php do { ?>

<div class="break">

// Contents taken from MySQL //

</div>

<?php } while ($row_displayPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($displayPosts)); ?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I think part of it is working but as you can see by the link provided it isn't moving the elements together vertically. Does anyone have any pointers?

WORKING UPDATE:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
          $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry({
              itemSelector : '.break',
              columnWidth : 429,
              gutterWidth : 40      //Added gutter to simulate margin
          });
        });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Possible the break that's floated left?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock In the masonry documentation is says use that mark up: `.item {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your script in JQuery's dom ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
          itemSelector : '.break',
          columnWidth : 429
      });
    });

});
```

Masonry isn't actually running on your page which is why your elements are just floated and not arranged how you expect them to be.

EDIT:

After downloading you page and playing around with it it seems that you need to also remove:

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

from your `.break` class

AS WELL AS wrapping the masonry script in `$(document).ready`

I suspect that your margins are makinbg the elements too wide to stack side by side

Comment: That stops it working all together, they just display as they would without the masonry script. Also I'm surprised masonry isn't actually running.. How can i enable it?

Comment: they're currently displaying the way they would without masonry. See what happens when you run the following in the console `$(".portfolio-container").masonry({ itemSelector: '.break' });`

Comment: @iliacholy It displays the `portfolio-container` div with its contents inside the console

Comment: @user1449737 did you just change something on the page you linked to? It worked a second ago ...

Comment: @iliacholy I've only added the JQuery's dom ready code 3rror404 suggested

Comment: Now it works thank you, but my element has no margin.. What can I do about that?

Comment: It looks like the correct way to add margins in Masonry is to use "gutterWidth: 40" Where "40" is your margin in pixels see documentation: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html

Comment: remember that your element width plus it's margins must not be wider than the container else it wont work.